# Convert ifconfig alias to netplan

Tags: networking, 22.04, netplan

When booting/after dhcp of enp0s25, I want to do:

```
ifconfig enp0s25:1 my-static-ip-addr
```

How can I do that on Ubuntu 22.04? Possibly using netplan?

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface aliases have long been deprecated by the kernel.  Instead, you assign multiple addresses to the same interface, such as:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: true
      addresses: [10.0.0.5/24]
```